# The figure made by using seaborn plots is too tight when set on top of each other

Tags: seaborn

I was recently doing some EDA on a data set.I created a boxplot, a countplot and a violinplot using seaborn and created an image using matplotlib. 
But the result is not very easy on the eye and looks very congested.
Is this normal? Any way to make it better ?

[This is the image of the notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbsbX.png)

Comment: `fig.tight_layout()` or `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2)` (where 0.2 should probably be a different value on a case by case basis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on your problem:)
In my opinion, the spacing is not the problem, the aspect ratio is. Your individual plots don't have enough height. So try to change te aspect ratio and see if you like it better. So change the first line to:

```
plt.Figure(figsize=(8, 12)
```

for example.